# If I already have the data from an XML, how do I save it in a table?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sqlxml

I already have the info from a XML but my problem is, how to save it in a local table?

```sql
DECLARE @docHandle int  
DECLARE @xmlDocument xml  
SET @xmlDocument = '
<Comprobante Fecha="2020-05-30" SubTotal="1324.56" Moneda="MXN" Total="1398.95" TipoDeComprobante="I" MetodoPago="PPD">
    <Emisor Rfc="SIH9511279T7" Nombre="HEB" RegimenFiscal="601"/>
    <Receptor Rfc="XXXX123456XXX" Nombre="USER" UsoCFDI="G03"/>
    <Conceptos>
        <Concepto ClaveProdServ="50404600" Cantidad="1.00" ClaveUnidad="H87" Unidad="PZ" Descripcion="LECHUGA" ValorUnitario="43.95" Importe="43.95">
            <Impuestos>
                <Traslados>
                    <Traslado Base="43.95" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.000000" Importe="0.00"/>
                    <Traslado Base="43.95" Impuesto="001" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="16.00"/>
                </Traslados>
            </Impuestos>
        </Concepto>
        <Concepto ClaveProdServ="42141606" Cantidad="1.00" ClaveUnidad="H87" Unidad="PZ" Descripcion="HUGGIES" ValorUnitario="438.79" Importe="438.79">
                <Impuestos>
                    <Traslados>
                        <Traslado Base="438.79" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="70.21"/>
                        <Traslado Base="438.79" Impuesto="003" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.080000" Importe="7.23"/>
                    </Traslados>
                </Impuestos>
        </Concepto>
    </Conceptos>
    <Impuestos TotalImpuestosTrasladados="74.39">
        <Traslados>
            <Traslado Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="70.21"/>
            <Traslado Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.000000" Importe="0.00"/>
            <Traslado Impuesto="003" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.080000" Importe="4.18"/>
        </Traslados>
    </Impuestos>
    <Complemento>
        <TimbreFiscalDigital Version="1.1" UUID="21C9FD4A" FechaTimbrado="2020-06-30T10:58:01" RfcProvCertif="EEL961104G96"/>
    </Complemento>
</Comprobante>
'
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle OUTPUT, @xmlDocument  
SELECT * 
FROM OPENXML (@docHandle, '/Comprobante/Conceptos/Concepto/Impuestos/Traslados/Traslado/@Importe')  
       WITH ( Imp1          money           '.',  
              Tasa          decimal(6,6)    '../@TasaOCuota',  
              Descrip       varchar(100)    '../../../../@Descripcion',
              Imp2          money           '../../../../@Importe',
              TotImp        money           '/Comprobante/Impuestos/@TotalImpuestosTrasladados',
              RFCEmisor     varchar(13)     '/Comprobante/Emisor/@Rfc',
              Fecha         date            '/Comprobante/@Fecha',
              UUID          varchar(50)     '/Comprobante/Complemento//TimbreFiscalDigital/@UUID',
              RFCReceptor   varchar(13)     '/Comprobante/Receptor/@Rfc')  
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @docHandle
```

This is the result:

| Imp1 | Tasa | Descrip | Imp2 | TotImp | RFCEmisor | Fecha | UUID | RFCReceptor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.00 | 0.000000 | LECHUCA | 43.95 | 74.39 | SIH9511279T7 | 2020-05-30 | 21C9FD4A | XXXX123456XXX |
| 16.00 | 0.160000 | LECHUGA | 43.95 | 74.39 | SIH9511279T7 | 2020-05-30 | 21C9FD4A | XXXX123456XXX |
| 70.21 | 0.160000 | HUGGIES | 438.79 | 74.39 | SIH9511279T7 | 2020-05-30 | 21C9FD4A | XXXX123456XXX |
| 7.23 | 0.000000 | HUGGIES | 438.79 | 74.39 | SIH9511279T7 | 2020-05-30 | 21C9FD4A | XXXX123456XXX |

Comment: I strongly suggest using XQUERY over those old sp's; which are really only there for compatibility reasons.

Comment: As for how you get the data, once you have it in a dataset, into a table; what's wrong with an `INSERT`?

Comment: I tried to do it with INSERT but, I'm new on this and this have been the problem: use INSERT on this. 'Cause I have another code with INSERT but, at the time when I want to get the data from XML, that is another problem

Comment: @IsraelAle `divide and conquer` - approach each problem, one at the time. Since you have the result. create a table *(with the same schema you build for read the XML)* and execute: `INSERT INTO <your_new_table> (fields) SELECT fields FROM <your_xml_schema>`. Then, read the data from `<your_new_table>` - which will have the XML data.

Comment: OMG!!! Thank u Marco! it works!